# Report Grouping by Date

Tags: reporting, formula-field, date, group-by

I'm relatively new to SF but gaining steam quickly. I've got Opportunities that include a contract start date and contact end date and I am trying to create a report that summarizes who we have contracts with in a particular year.

I added contract start date to the grouping field and grouped by year which worked for the most part. The issue I am having is with the length of our contracts.  Some are for multiple years and therefore aren't showing up in certain groups. For example if a contract is from 2015-2018 it won't show up in 2016 because I've grouped it by start date, which makes complete sense.

I've poked around with formulas but keep getting the error that my fields don't exist and I'm not even sure which formula I could use or if this is the right avenue to be taking.

Comment: You can put relevant pictures of your usecase and where you are facing issue

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to add Filter Logic to your report.  That lets you have more sophisticated conditions like

```
((1 AND 2) OR (3 AND 4)) or 5
```

in your case, you need to add something like these conditions

```
Condition X: Contract Start Date < 2016
Condition Y: Contract End Date > 2016
```

and add

```
"... (X AND Y)
```

to your filter logic.  This assumes you are doing the report for a specific year as you appear to be saying.  The literal, "THIS_YEAR" can be used if you always want to run the report for the current year.